# Can't install pyethereum module

Tags: python, ubuntu, ethereum

I'm new in Ethereum, so probably that's a silly question.

Now I'm trying to install serpent and pyethereum according to this [tutorial](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Serpent). Everything works well, but when I'm launching Python's code:

```
import serpent
import pyethereum
```

There is an error: `No module named pyethereum`

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The module's name is `ethereum`, not `pyethereum`. Using the following:

```
import serpent
import ethereum
```

should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot! For those, who read this [Serpent tutorial](https://mc2-umd.github.io/ethereumlab/docs/serpent_tutorial.pdf) - now it's outdated :(

Answer (score 1):

Follow the installation instructions from [Pytherium's Readme](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum), which read:

```
git clone https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum/
cd pyethereum
python setup.py install
```

In the tutorial's instructions, `develop` branch is used, which seems to be failing according to the continuous integration badges.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work for me. I completely removed previous pyethereum folder, repeat your instructions, but still the same error.